# When using my Apple ID, how can I sign out from within an app?

Tags: ios

I have successfully managed to log into an app using the Apple Authentication functionality.

I am now trying to log out, and the only way I have found is through the Settings → Apple ID → Password & Security → Apps Using Your Apple ID.

I would be very surprised if there is no other way to do this from within the application, as it would make more sense. Most common users don't even know they can do this from within their settings.

Comment: That setting is to remove the association between the Sign In with Apple and your app. This is effectively deleting the account.  The user does not want to do this routinely. To sign out of your app, you simply discard the token you have cached, requiring them to sign in again if they want to use your app; this will seamlessly sign them back in with the same account. Sign In with Apple is deliberately designed to use a single account in your app per Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Apple does not have a sign out function available to use for the "Sign in with Apple". Currently, the user must go into the Settings application and revoke permission.

Comment: Deleting an account is very different to signing out no?

Comment: It all depends how you program each functionality - it can be exactly the same.